# incompatible type while adding value to Map

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have one ArrayList filled with Rectangles. I want to add the contents to Map where Key will be X coordinate and value is List which has same X cord.

I can do this by having a function

```
void dummyFun(List<Rectangle> listRects)
{
    Map<Integer, List<Rectangle>> mapSameXCordRectangles = new HashMap<>();
    listRects.forEach((Rectangle table) ->
    {
        if(mapSameXCordRectangles.containsKey(table.x))
        {
            mapSameXCordRectangles.get(table.x).add(table);
        }
        else
        {
            List<Rectangle> lstRect = new ArrayList<>();
            lstRect.add(table);
            mapSameXCordRectangles.put(table.x, lstRect);
        }
    });
}
```

But i want to remove if-else Statement with something like below.

```
void dummyFun1(List<Rectangle> listRects)
{
    Map<Integer, List<Rectangle>> mapSameXCordRectangles = new HashMap<>();
    List<Rectangle> lstTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    listRects.forEach((Rectangle table) ->
    {
        mapSameXCordRectangles.put(table.x,mapSameXCordRectangles.containsKey(table.x) ? mapSameXCordRectangles.get(table.x).add(table): new ArrayList<>().add(table));
    });
}
```

When I do this I get error as Boolean can't be converted as List.
When i add new Rectangle to the ArrayList in the map or create new ArrayList it returns boolean instead of that i want it to return ArrayList.

How can I do this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Map<Integer, List<Rectangle>> map = listRects.stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.x));
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets have a look at your code:

```
mapSameXCordRectangles.put(
  table.x,
  mapSameXCordRectangles.containsKey(table.x) ?  
    mapSameXCordRectangles.get(table.x).add(table) : 
  new ArrayList<>().add(table));
```

Your boolean ?: works fine; your problem is: calling [List.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) returns a **boolean** value. And your Map is simply not **accepting** boolean values!

One option to avoid that problem: use some temporary list object to work on:

```
List<Rectangle> workingList =
  mapSameXCordRectangles.containsKey(table.x) ?  
    mapSameXCordRectangles.get(table.x) : 
    new ArrayList<>());
workingList.add(table);
mapSameXCordRectangles.put(
  table.x, workingList);
```

I would recommend such a style anyway. Sometimes people think it is "great" to push as many statements as possible into a single line; but the thing is: code should be written to be **readable**. And I actually think that my suggestion here is also easier to digest than your initial input.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.